# django app on server: I moved from python 2.7 to 3.5 and apache2 can't find django

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I have a Django (v1.11.6) app on my Ubuntu server and was using Python v2.7.

I am now using Python 3.5 (not using `virtualenv`), however when I run `sudo service apache2 restart` I get the following error:

```
[Mon Oct 23 12:50:22.001339 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28871] [client 194.42.16.145:28999]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Oct 23 12:50:22.001360 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28871] [client 194.42.16.145:28999] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

When I run `python3 manage.py runserver` I get no error.

Comment: "I'm not using virtualenv." - It sounds as though you already know the solution... it looks like apache is using a different environment to you

Comment: @Sayse When I was using python 2.7 the app was working!

Comment: yes... because, again, that was a different python environment.

Comment: @Sayse So, what do you propose?

Comment: You need to install Django for your Python3 environment.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That was it. You may add it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Django into your Python 3 environment. Run:

```
pip3 install django
```

or

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv --python=python3 mynewenv
source mynewenv/bin/activate
pip install django
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-django
```

[Based on [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) comment]

Comment: For me it worked using `sudo apt-get install python3-django`.